# PHP Regular expression is failing

Tags: php, regex

I have a file with section headings that look like this:

```
PLAY [Global Inventory] ********************************************************
```

I'm using PHP to parse the file, but I'm having trouble getting my regular expression down correctly.  I need to extract "Global Inventory" from the above section title.

Here's what I have so far:

```
function check_section_type($row) {
        $pattern = '/PLAY(\s*)(\[)([a-z\s]*)(\])(\**)/i';
        preg_match($pattern, $row, $matches);
        var_dump($matches);
}
```

The var dump command returns an empty array...
I've tried a few variations of the pattern but I can't see where I'm going wrong. 
Other patterns I tried:

```
$pattern = '/PLAY(\s*)(\[)([a-zA-Z\s]*)(\])(\**)/i';
```

and

```
 $pattern = '/PLAY(\s*)(\[[a-zA-Z\s]\]*)(\])(\**)/i';
```

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: are you sure that when you call the function, `$row` contains the correct input? Because I just tested it and it seems to be working fine.

Comment: [`/PLAY\h*\[([A-Za-z\s]*)\]\h*\**/` should work](https://regex101.com/r/mN5mH3/1)

Comment: [Demo](https://ideone.com/kxisuy).

Comment: I'd simplify it a bit by removing some unnecessary matching groups.  `$pattern = '/PLAY\s+\[([^\]]*)\]\**/i';`

Comment: @treegarden, yes i'm an idiot.  i had some blank lines that were throwing me off.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider the following regexp:

```
$str = "PLAY [Global Inventory] ********************************************************";
preg_match("/PLAY \[([^]]+?)\]/iu", $str, $matches);

print_r($matches[1]);   // "Global Inventory"
```

Comment: what is the "u" for at the end pls?

Comment: *u (PCRE_UTF8)*
This modifier turns on additional functionality of PCRE that is incompatible with Perl. Pattern and subject strings are treated as UTF-8.